# Can't find method in a package

Tags: python, image, image-processing, graphics, signal-processing

Below code when run throws

```
AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageChops' has no attribute 'overlay'
```

error.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

im1= Image.open(r'.\white.jpg')
im2= Image.open(r'.\green.jpg')

result = ImageChops.overlay(im1, im2)

plt.imshow(result)
```

It should have this method as per reference:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageChops.html.
How can I correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your version of Pillow. It must be >= 7.1.0 as in the [release notes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/7.1.0.html?highlight=overlay#new-channel-operations):

> New channel operations
>
> Three new channel operations have been added: soft_light(),
> hard_light() and **`overlay()`**.

Update via `python3 -m pip install Pillow==7.1` or a more later one.

Using 7.0

```
>>> from PIL import ImageChops
>>> ImageChops.overlay
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageChops' has no attribute 'overlay'
```

Using 7.1 (or later)

```
>>> from PIL import ImageChops
>>> ImageChops.overlay
<function overlay at 0x7f766112ff70>
```